# Change store_dir, move old files to new path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I need to change the store_dir for my Carrierwave uploader. 
Unfortunately this will break the paths of all existing files stored 
in the old store_dir.  What is the safest way to copy/move these old 
images to the new store_dir path and update their filenames.

Thank you.